# Certain website won't load on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

The problem only occurs on one website. I am using the latest version of Firefox in the repository, but it also happens with chromium.

Every time I try to load it it just keeps loading and shows no errors at all. Even when I try to use ping on the website, it doesn't time out it just freezes. But it loads on windows just fine.

What's really puzzling is that when I clear Firefox history it works for a few minutes before the same problem happens again.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Hard to answer without the specific URL. Did you try with other Linux browsers (Chromium, etc...)?

Comment: The problem happens with freelancer.com, and yes I tried Chromium with the same result.

Comment: Works for me in 16.04 with both FF and Chromium. Tried `wget` or `curl`? Maybe you'll get a meaningful error message.

Comment: **wget** downloads the index.html properly but **curl** gives me `301 Moved Permanently` Error

Comment: Wget shows it's not to your network. 301 isn't really an error, the HTTP client can use that to fetch the new address, and here I think it's juts forwarding to the HTTPS address (`curl https://www.freelancer.com` gets the file). Maybe try the HTTPS URL directly? The target being HTTPS it could be a problem of validating the site's certificate.

Comment: Yes it works, curl downloads the html page. Which means the problem is with the browsers.

Comment: More accurately, it is a problem with your browser setup since it works with mine. What do you see when you use the HTTPS URL in your browser?

Comment: Every time Firefox is stuck on `Waiting for www.freelancer.com` for a few **minutes** and then stops with no error message. I've noticed the same behavior from Chromium.
PS: It only happens when I'm logged into an account.